# how to set http as the project default url in gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab

when opening a project in gitlab, you will see SSH and HTTP(or HTTPS) url on the top of project home page, the SSH url is as default, but I want to set  HTTP(or HTTPS) as default, so how should I do? Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`app/views/shared/_clone_panel.html.haml`](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/4d7792bc388d72a8ce6c2f84e102ba68a28dae81/app/views/shared/_clone_panel.html.haml#L4-L5) file does show:

```
.git-clone-holder.input-group
  .input-group-btn
    %button{class: "btn #{ 'active' if default_clone_protocol == 'ssh' }", :"data-clone" => project.ssh_url_to_repo} SSH
    %button{class: "btn #{ 'active' if default_clone_protocol == 'http' }", :"data-clone" => project.http_url_to_repo}= gitlab_config.protocol.upcase
```

And that default_clone_protocol is defined in [`app/helpers/projects_helper.rb`](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/4d7792bc388d72a8ce6c2f84e102ba68a28dae81/app/helpers/projects_helper.rb#L188-L190)

```
def default_clone_protocol
    current_user ? "ssh" : "http"
end
```

So you could change that code, or add a setting in [`config/gitlab.yml.example`](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/config/gitlab.yml.example) in order to make it a parameter.

As mentioned by [Mosi Wang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3781404/mosi-wang)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24442664/6309), the function [`default_url_to_repo`](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/4d7792bc388d72a8ce6c2f84e102ba68a28dae81/app/helpers/projects_helper.rb#L183-L186) also plays a role in the definition of that order, since it returns `project.url_to_repo : project.http_url_to_repo`.
Reversing the order can help too.

Comment: thanks for your reply, and I can't find the setting in gitlab.yml, I want to change it in gitlab.yml, and it is an easy and safety way to do. so can you tell me which line should i change? Or I have to change the code.

Comment: @yegomo no, my point was to say it *is not* yey an easy setting: if you want to change the default you would for now have to change the `projects_helper.rb` code. That could be a good idea for a pull request though.

Answer (score 10):

infact, you have to modify 2 other lines above the default_clone_protocol.

```
def default_url_to_repo(project = nil)
  project = project || @project
  current_user ? project.http_url_to_repo : project.url_to_repo
end

def default_clone_protocol
  current_user ? "http" : "ssh"
end
```

Comment: Good catch regarding the `default_url_to_repo` function. +1

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled over this problem while running several Gitlab accounts on the same machine which required different settings concerning the access protocol but every post I saw related to changes in the settings globally. To avoid configuration problems I looked for a way to change the settings for every project locally. Following steps fixed my problems:

1. Open the terminal and change into your projects .git folder.

> cd my_project/.git

2. Open the browser. Navigate to the Gitlab repo. Click blue "Clone" button. Copy the URL for cloning via https.
3. Switch to the terminal again. Edit the file named "config" located int the .git folder. I used "Vim" for editing.

> vi config

4. Change line with the existing url in the [remote "origin"] block to:

> url = **"paste copied url"**

Answer (score -1):

If this is still important to you, consider commenting on https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/merge_requests/1811 or https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/3504. If this request is approved, it will solve your problem in the standard product. The merge request is being considered "as we speak".

Comment: Hi, you should use the comment box instead of making a new answer, as it's not really a solution to the author problem.

Comment: True, that. I'll do it differently next time.